# Why does my Spring Boot app exit with 'Can not access application.jar file' error when running docker-compose up?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockernize my Spring boot Project. I'm using postgres as Database. When I run docker-compose up, the database container is running ok, but the app is always excited with error: Can not access application.jar file.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:latest
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=./target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app/application.jar
ARG HOTEL_CSV=./src/main/resources/data/hotels.csv
COPY ${HOTEL_CSV} /app/data/hotels.csv
ARG OFFERS=./src/main/resources/data/offers.csv
COPY ${OFFERS} /app/data/offers.csv

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: ./
    image: holiday-backend-app-1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./data:/app/data
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: org.postgresql.Driver
      SPRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL: "true"
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: create-drop
      SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      server.port: 8080
      server.address: 0.0.0.0

  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
```

`db-container logs, in case it's improtant`

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok


Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

waiting for server to start....2023-05-22 05:17:58.982 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-05-22 05:17:58.984 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-05-22 05:17:58.990 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-22 05:17:58 UTC
2023-05-22 05:17:58.997 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

waiting for server to shut down...2023-05-22 05:17:59.103 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
.2023-05-22 05:17:59.105 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-05-22 05:17:59.109 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
2023-05-22 05:17:59.112 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
2023-05-22 05:17:59.113 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-05-22 05:17:59.122 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.003 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.010 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-05-22 05:17:59.130 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2023-05-22 05:17:59.234 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-05-22 05:17:59.234 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-05-22 05:17:59.234 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-05-22 05:17:59.237 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-05-22 05:17:59.242 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-22 05:17:59 UTC
2023-05-22 05:17:59.248 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

When I try to run with java -jar command, everything is fine. I don't know how to fix this problem. Pls help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If workdir = ```/app```,  then why are you calling ```./app/application.jar```?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. I made a mistake there, and I changed it from './app/application.jar' to 'application.jar' However, when I try to rebuild, I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the entire `volumes:` block.

In the Dockerfile, the `/app` directory contains `application.jar` and a `data` subdirectory.  That subdirectory contains two files `hotels.csv` and `offers.csv`.  You mount different host directories over those two container directories; if the project root directory (and not `target`) doesn't contain `application.jar` then you'll get some sort of "not found" error.

You can see this more directly running temporary containers to peek into the container filesystem

```bash
docker-compose run app ls       # no application.jar
docker-compose run app ls data  # likely empty
```

(The two CSV files look like they should be built into your jar file already.  You might use the Spring `ResourceLoader` interface to access them via `classpath:/data/offers.csv` rather than copy them as separate files.)

Comment: Hi, I deleted the volumes block and made some minor changed. It works now, so thanks a lot.